# Deleting the last added row in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have looked at the all the provided solutions here but none seems to help with my specific problem.

I am creating rows dynamically in GridView which is working great.

However, we would like to delete the last row added.

My code is deleting the default row which is the first row.

Any ideas what I need to modify to ensure that only the last added row gets deleted when user clicks the Delete button?

```
//Markup

      <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" RowStyle-Wrap="false" gridlines="None" CssClass="responsiveTable1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting" OnRowCreated="Gridview1_RowCreated">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" Visible="false" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
         <headerstyle horizontalalign="Left" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtsourcename" placeholder="Name...(e.g, Jane Doe)" runat="server" style="width:375px;" AutoPostBack="true" class="form-control textClass" OnTextChanged="txtsourcename_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="grid1Details" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Grid1CheckChanged" /><span style="color:#ff0000">*Check this box if N/A</span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtsourceaddress" placeholder="Address..." runat="server" style="width:375px;" class="form-control textClass"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" 
                    onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" CssClass="grvAddButton" /><br /><br /><br>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="sourceDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
                     CssClass="grvDelButton" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this row?')"  /> <br /><br /><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        </Columns>
      </asp:gridview>
```

//VB

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
        Dim lb As Button = CType(e.Row.FindControl("sourceDelete"), Button)
        If lb IsNot Nothing Then
            If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                If e.Row.RowIndex = dt.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                    lb.Visible = False
                End If
            Else
                lb.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

    Protected Sub sourceDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim lb As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = CType(lb.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim rowID As Integer = gvRow.RowIndex
        If ViewState("CurrentTable") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dt As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                If gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                    dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows(rowID))
                    ResetRowID(dt)
                End If
            End If

            ViewState("CurrentTable") = dt
            Gridview1.DataSource = dt
            Gridview1.DataBind()
        End If

        SetPreviousData()
End Sub

    Private Sub ResetRowID(ByVal dt As DataTable)
        Dim rowNumber As Integer = 1
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                row(0) = rowNumber
                rowNumber += 1
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any code sorting the rows, so wouldn't the last added row be at the index of Count() - 1?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that below line deletes a specific row

```
dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows(rowID))
```

try remove the count of dt - 1

```
dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.count() -1))
```

Comment: my apologies if this is not explained well. Plese see the updated information at the top with screenshot that explains what I am trying to do. For instance, if user fills out the first row, clicks Add to add a new row, then changes his/her mind, how that newly added row be removed?